# Basic Full Page setup is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullPage.js for my website. I went to test it and it isn't functioning like it is supposed to and creating a full height page. I tried changing the scripts and links around, as well as using different jQuery Libraries. All the sources are 100% correct. Any leads or suggestions? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap / CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.8/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="fullpage"> <!-- Contains all content that uses FullPage-->
            <div class="section">
                <h1>hello</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <h1>hello</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <h1>hello</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#wrapper').fullpage();
            });
        </script>


        <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And "not working" means...?

Comment: Try to add css files first, and then js files (change order of full page css and full page js)... It should be ok to place all js files at the bottom of the body tag. E.g. check order of script and styles here: http://demo.w3developer.de/fullpage/

Comment: not working means that the full page plugin is not in use @Clive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

library :: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fullPage.js

so you have to change the src attribute of script file . 
since you are using src of full page is `jquery.fullPage.js` but that is not valid .

use https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.8/jquery.fullPage.js in src attribute .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.8/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.8/jquery.fullPage.css" />


    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="wrapper"> <!-- Contains all content that uses FullPage-->
            <div class="section">
                <h1>hello</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <h1>hello</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <h1>hello</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#wrapper').fullpage();
            });
        </script>


        <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This still didn't work for me. I also added CSS first before JS and still to no avail does the full page setting work.

Comment: Thank you @Mahi I must ask though in case I run into this problem in the future. Was my issue just incorrect order of scripts/links? Thanks again.

Comment: no the order was correct but you have given the src file wrong in href attribute . since `jquery.fullPage.js` is not a file in server

Answer (score -1):

Change `id="wrapper"` to `id="fullpage"`

Default structure looks like below:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">
         <div class="slide"> Slide 1 </div>
         <div class="slide"> Slide 2 </div>
         <div class="slide"> Slide 3 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not correct. You can pass any element ID name you want for the wrapper element. This is not the source of his issue.

Comment: I believe you can use any element ID you prefer from what I read on github. But I did try this and it did not work.

Comment: You can. Just used fullpage.js in the last site I built. You can give it any element (except for the body) to use as the wrapper.